# $\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}f_{j}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = 0 $ $\forall (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $n\geq 2$ be an odd integer. Prove that there is no function $f := (f_{1}, f_{2}, \ldots, f_{n})$ of class $C^{\infty}$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}f_{j}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = 0 $ $\forall (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$.

This question is from concours SMF junior 2020 https://smf.emath.fr/evenements-smf/annonce-concours-smf-junior-2020

I only know the case where $f$ is linear. If $f$ is linear, we represent $f$ by an matrix $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $\forall x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$, $x^\top Ax = 0$. So $A$ is antisymetric. Since $\det(A) = \det(A^\top) = (-1)^{n}\det(A)$ and $n$ is odd, so $\det(A) = 0$. But $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\} \Rightarrow Ax\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$ means that $\ker(A) = 0$. Impossible.

In general case, we have $df(x)(x)+f(x) = 0$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$. I'm not sure if this is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given condition is $\langle x,f(x)\rangle = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$. This means that the restriction $f|_{\Bbb S^{n-1}}$ defines a vector field on the sphere $\Bbb S^{n-1}$, since $x \in \Bbb S^{n-1}$ and $\langle x,f(x)\rangle = 0$ means that $f(x) \in x^\perp = T_x(\Bbb S^{n-1})$. Since $n$ is odd, $n-1$ is even. So by the [hairy-ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), there is $x_0 \in \Bbb S^{n-1}$ with $f(x_0) = 0$. But this contradicts your assumption that $f$ takes values in $\Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$.